# incompatible types when assigning to type 'int’ from type ‘struct' and vice versa

Tags: c, struct, int

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
struct protein
{
    char proteinBrand[100];
    int currentStock;
    int unitsSold;
    double averageReview;
    int totalReviews;
};

void selection_sort(struct protein protein_powders[], int n)
{
    int i, largest = 0, temp;
    if (n == 1)
            return;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if (protein_powders[i].averageReview < protein_powders[largest].averageReview)
                    largest = i;
    if (largest < n - 1) {
            temp = protein_powders[n-1];
            protein_powders[n-1] = protein_powders[largest];
            protein_powders[largest] = temp;
    }
}
```

The lines in question are

```
temp = protein_powders[n-1];
```

and

```
protein_powders[largest] = temp;
```

I get these compiler errors and I don't really know what to change. I'm not too experienced in C so any help would be appreciated!:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘struct protein’

incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct protein’ from type ‘int’
```

Comment: Shouldn't `temp` be a protein struct, `struct protein temp = protein_powders[n-1]`?

Comment: `temp` is an `int`, `protein_powders` is an array of `struct protein`. You're trying to equate apples and oranges. There are some `int`s _within_ the struct you could equate `temp` to, such as `currentStock`. `temp = protein_powders[n-1].currentStock;` for instance. Completely depends on what you're trying to do of course.

Comment: the code uses a varible `largest` as an index into the `protein_powers[] array.  but this code block: `if (protein_powders[i].averageReview < protein_powders[largest].averageReview)
                    largest = i;` :   is setting the variable `largest` to be the index of smallest.   Given the name of the variable,, I suspect the `<` should be: `>`

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are trying to assign a element of type `protein` to an integer variable.
Like I pointed out in my comment, `temp` should be declared as a struct to use the way you do right now:

```
// Declare temp as a struct.
struct protein temp;

// And then use it.
temp = protein_powers[n-1];
```

If your intention is to just assign a value you could do like this:

```
int temp = protein_powers[n-1].currentStock;
```